# Stock Items in Magento-2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I'm updated stock details  programmatically.And then performed to reindex .I can get indexerCollection.But I want to get only stock.How  to do this?

This is my reindex code........

```
protected function changeIndexMode($mode)
{

    $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    foreach ($indexerCollection as $indexer) {
        if ($mode == 'UPDATE_BY_SCHEDULE') {
            $indexer->setScheduled(true);
        } else if ($mode == 'UPDATE_ON_SAVE') {
            $indexer->setScheduled(false);
        } else if ($mode == 'REINDEX') {
            $reindex = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load('cataloginventory_stock');
            $reindex->reindexAll($indexer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below,

**For stock indexer id is cataloginventory_stock**

```
$reindex = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load('cataloginventory_stock');
$reindex->reindexAll($indexer);
```

If you need any other indexer id you can get it from below,

```
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid  (Design Config Grid)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid  (Customer Grid)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_flat  (Product flat data)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_flat (Category Flat data
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product (Category Products)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category (Product Categories)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price (Product price index)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute (Product Eav Index)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock (Stock Index)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_rule (Catalog Rule Product)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_product (Catalog Product Rule)
 - php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext  (Catalog Search index)
```

Comment: I can get indexerCollection .But i want to get cataloginventory_stock .how to do this.see my updated post.@Rakesh

Comment: You can print $indexer to check in foreach.

Comment: You can print $indexer to check in foreach.

Answer (score 0):

as @Rakesh mentioned, to reindex stock programatticaly you can use index id to to re-index individual indexer :

catalog_category_product                 **Category Products**

catalog_product_category                 **Product Categories**

catalog_product_price                    **Product Price**

catalog_product_attribute                **Product EAV**

cataloginventory_stock                   **Stock**

catalogrule_rule                         **Catalog Rule Product**

catalogrule_product                      **Catalog Product Rule**

catalogsearch_fulltext                   **Catalog Search**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

so for indexing only stock inventory code will be like:

```
$reindex = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load('cataloginventory_stock');
$reindex->reindexAll($indexer);
```

and its full code block would be :

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
*/
protected $_indexerFactory;
/**
* @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
*/
protected $_indexerCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
   \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
   \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
){
   $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
   $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}



// you can call this function to do reindexing
  public function reIndexing(){
     $reindex = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load('cataloginventory_stock');
   $reindex->reindexAll($indexer);
 }
```

Comment: please see my updated post